# Objective-c NSMutableArray release behaviour

Tags: objective-c

Does the release, recursively releases all inner objects? or must it be done manualy?

Can I do just this?

```
NSMutableArray *list = [[NSArray alloc] init];
// ...
// fill list with elements
//...
[list release];
```

Or must I release all inner objects one by one before releasing the NSMutableArray? // Suposing there isn't any other reference to the contained objects, except on the list itself.

Comment: I deleted my answer from Feb 2011, as it contained incorrect info. In it I stated that you need to use [x removeAllObjects] in order to ensure the contained objects are released. This is sort of true: if you created a NSMutableArray using [[NSMutableArray alloc] init], it is certainly not true. To ensure the contained objects in an AUTORELEASED NSMutableArray are removed &sent a release, when you are done with it, and not when the array is eventually released by the pool, it does apply. aside from naivety, what threw me off is that above code actually typecasts an NSArray to NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does.  It retains them when added, and releases them when dealloc'd.  This is actually one of the most common questions I see here.

Comment: i just got started with objective-c tks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are owning the object then you will have to release it.

```
    NSMutableArray *list = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] init] // you are the owner of this object
    [list addObject:str];
    [str release]; // release the object after using it
    [list release];
```

If you are not the owner of the object then you should not release.

```
    NSMutableArray *list = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    NSString *str = [NSString string]; // you are not owning this object
    [list addObject:str]; // str retain count is incremented
    [list release];  // str retain count is decremented.
```

This is the concept which even array also uses. When you add any object to the array, array will retain it. In the sense it becomes the owner of that object and It will release that object when you release the array.